# ra-supabase how to access usePermissions

Tags: permissions, react-admin, supabase, authprovider

I'm trying to follow the [documentation] (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Permissions.html) to have one of the resources only available to some users with supabase.

However when I look into the authProvide.ts to check the supabaseAuthProvider i can see the lines are empty for that hook (in node_module/ra-supabase-core/src)

```
file located at: 
node_module/ra-supabase-core/src/authProvider.ts


export const supabaseAuthProvider = (
    client: SupabaseClient,
    { getIdentity, redirectTo }: SupabaseAuthProviderOptions
): SupabaseAuthProvider => {
    return {
        async login(params) {
            // some code here
        },

        // other functions here
        
        async getPermissions() {
            return;
        },
        async getIdentity() {
           // some code here
        },
    };
};
```

does that mean the getPermissions() is not (yet?) supported with supabase? Should I copy the content of that file and use as my own custom authProvider, adding the missing code?

Thanks a lot

Edit
Still looking around, what I found today is that

```
//src/AuthProvider.jsx

import { supabaseAuthProvider } from 'ra-supabase'
import { supabaseClient } from './supabaseClient'

export const authProvider = supabaseAuthProvider(supabaseClient, {
  getIdentity: async (user) => {
    const { data, error } = await supabaseClient
      .from('profiles')
      .select('id, name, apelido')
      .match({ email: user.email })
      .single()

    if (!data || error) {
      throw new Error()
    }

    return {
      id: data.id,
      fullName: `${data.name} ${data.apelido}`,
    }
  },
  getPermissions: async () => {
    console.log('getPermissions')
    const user = supabaseClient.auth.user()
    return user ? user.app_metadata.groups : []
  },
})
```

Even thought the getIdentity is working well, I never get the getPermissions from the console.log, is that normal?

Thanks

-- Edit 2024-02-22

Hello,

so as I understand getPermissions will hopefully get implemented.

I tried to use the usePermissions hook as suggested, but it remains undefined, here below is what I have tried.

```
//ProfileList.jsx
import {
  Datagrid,
  DateField,
  List,
  TextField,
  usePermissions,
} from 'react-admin'

export const ProfileList = () => {
  const { permissions } = usePermissions()

  return (
    <List>
      <Datagrid bulkActionButtons={false} rowClick='edit'>
        <DateField source='updated_at' />
        <TextField source='username' />
        {permissions === 'right' ? (
          <TextField source='fullname' />
        ) : (
          console.log(permissions)
        )}
        <TextField source='avatar_url' />
        <TextField source='website' />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  )
}
```

the code above returned undefined from the ProfileList, and the console.log from the getPermissions never gets called, so I am still not getting why the usePermissions is not calling my getPermissions defined in my authProvider.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, until now you have to implement yourself the `getPermissions` method, but fortunately there is [pull request](https://github.com/marmelab/ra-supabase/pull/50) to enhance this.

Secondly, [As the documentation explains](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AuthProviderWriting.html#getpermissions), React-admin doesn’t use permissions by default, but it provides the [`usePermissions` hook](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/usePermissions.html) to retrieve the permissions of the current user. That means that you'll see your log in the console by calling the `usePermissions` hook.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your feedback, I've edited my question above to address more points. I hope this pull request will get through soon